# Decomposing Hamiltonian in terms of Pauli strings

Tags: matrix, physics, quantum-computing

Does anyone know of a native Mathematica function or a package that allows one to decompose an arbitrary Hamiltonian into Pauli strings? There are a few packages for Python that do this (e.g., one from Pennylane), but I don't know of any for Mathematica.

If not, does anyone have any insight on how to write my own function to do this for any $2^n \times 2^n$ Hamiltonian, where $n$ is a positive integer?

Comment: [`PauliAlgebra`](https://github.com/EverettYou/PauliAlgebra) by Yizhuang You?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I looked at this package briefly before but I don't think it has what I need. I only took a very quick look, so I can take a closer look and see if there is anything hidden that I missed.

Comment: Especially the function `Abstract` defined in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not actually know what a Pauli string is, but I am going to guess that it means that we want to write a matrix as a linear combination of Kronecker products of Pauli matrices.

```
ToPauliStrings[A_]:=With[{n=Log2[Length[A]]},
  Most[ArrayRules[Nest[Transpose[#.ToPauliStringsAux,RotateRight[Range[1,n]]]&,
    Flatten[ArrayReshape[A,ConstantArray[2,2*n]],Array[{#,#+n}&,n]],n]]]];
ToPauliStringsAux=Inverse[Table[Flatten[PauliMatrix[i]],{i,1,4}]];

FromPauliStrings[ps_]:=Sum[p[[2]]*KroneckerProduct@@Map[PauliMatrix,p[[1]]],{p,ps}];
```

**Example 1:**

```
A1 = 7*KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1],PauliMatrix[3],PauliMatrix[1]];
ToPauliStrings[A1]
(* {{1,3,1}->7} *)
```

**Example 2:** Check that `ToPauliStrings` is inverse to `FromPauliStrings`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
A2 = RandomComplex[{-1-I,1+I},{32,32}];
FromPauliStrings[ToPauliStrings[A2]]-A2//Flatten//Norm//Chop
(* 0 *)
```

**Note.** The function `FromPauliStrings` is somewhat slow even for small `n`. I only included it to be able to check that `ToPauliStrings` works correctly.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! I know it is slow, it is known to be a problem with complexity exponential in the input, but luckily I am not worrying about that aspect right now ;) Thanks!